# MVC5 Get logged in user email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, google-signin

I have configured my Asp.Net MVC 5 app to use external logins (and I don't intend to use local logins).
To get the email address of the logged in user, I am doing this

```
Membership.GetUser().Email
```

But that is throwing

```
Host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I am able to connect to the database fine. Log in, log out, fetch other data. 
This works fine too.

```
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

The system blows up only when using Membership stuff.

ConnectionString configured in here doesnot exist in the web.config. Wonder how it is working it out!

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
            <providers>
                <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
                <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" ... />
            </providers>
        </membership>
```

If I update the connection string to the existing, working EF one, it complains it doesnt support the keyword *metadata*.

The email address is present in `aspnetusers` table. I am sure I can fetch it manually by calling the db, but I wonder if Asp.Net already does this for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

`user` will contain the email address for the user.